# R - How to use data from two dataframe to calculate new variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

i'm kind of newby in R and i'm trying real hard to explain as clearly as possible the problem i'm facing. And my english is not that good, sorry in advance.

I have two dataframes, one with thousands of lines, which are polygon numbers, and 13 variables.

The other dataframe is a weigthing grid for each variables, that I'm trying to apply on the first dataframe.
Here is a picture of the second dataframe : [weighting grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsjPu.png)

I'm trying to calculate new variables for each polygons (lines in my first dataframe), using the values of the second dataframe. For example, my first variable created would be FON_ECOL = param1 x 1 + param2 x 0.5 + param3 x 1
All the numbers (1, 0.5, 1 and 2) are in the weighting grid.

Here are codes for what the dataframes looks like :

```
df1 <- data.frame(IDMH=c('MH1','MH2','MH3'), param1 =c(0.5,1,0.005), param2=c(0,0.1,2), param3=c(4,5,6)) 
IDMH param1 param2 param3
MH1  0.5    0      4     
MH2  1      0.1    5
MH3  0.005  2      6

df2 <- data.frame(Parameters=c('param1','param2','param3'), FON_ECOL =c(1,0.5,1), BIOD=c(0,0,1), MEN=c(1,1,0)) 
Parameters FON_ECOL BIOD MEN
param1     1        0    1     
param2     0.5      0    1  
param3     1        1    0
```

Thanks a lot for your help, every insight will be usefull !
Let me know if I can explain more, or add .csv

Comment: If I understood you correctly, do you want to multiply your `df1` with `df2` like you multiply two matrices?

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dplyr/tidyr approach. It combines `df1` with the summary columns. Those summary columns are calculated by reshaping df1 longer, joining that to `df2`, and then summing the weighted values for the FON_ECOL:MEN columns within each `IDMH` group.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
left_join(
  df1, 
  df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(-IDMH, names_to = "Parameters") %>%
    left_join(df2) %>%
    group_by(IDMH) %>%
    summarize(across(FON_ECOL:MEN, ~sum(.x * value))))


  IDMH param1 param2 param3 FON_ECOL BIOD   MEN
1  MH1  0.500    0.0      4    4.500    4 0.500
2  MH2  1.000    0.1      5    6.050    5 1.100
3  MH3  0.005    2.0      6    7.005    6 2.005
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot for your time, it's sooooo helpful.